# AKReverb2 in AudioKit macOS Framework?

Tags: audiokit

The macOS 4.7.1 AudioKit Framework does not seem to include AKReverb2 like the iOS.  Not sure if there is a technical reason for this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reverb based on Apple's built-in DSP and it just isn't included on macOS.